# How to bind DataRow to the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, datarow

I have one datatable which has four or five columns. I dont know exactly the columns name and its count. But I want to bind the first row of the datatable into the GridView. How to do this? I need all your suggestions please.

Comment: Which version of .net framework you have?

Comment: @AVD: .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: Use FormView or Detailsview instead of "GridView".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq should be helpful here to get first item.

```
 var Temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Not applicable.. as take is not available.

Comment: Can you try dt.AsEnumerable().Take(1)   ?

Comment: Error Given = "The data source does not support server-side data paging."

Comment: I am using  var temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(1); in my code and then assigning it to grid which works fine. where exactly are you getting thing exception?

Comment: when i bind that temp to gridview.

Comment: var temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(1).CopyToDataTable()      should definitely work

Comment: @Sikender: How to use this in for loop? which is used to bind row by row.

Comment: @thevan: why do you want it in loop when when is only one row? you can use GridView.RowDataBound event to access rows

Comment: @Junaid: Actually I am doing for to generate report. Its functionality is to bind one row into gridview and print like wise it goes on...

Comment: DataTable temp = new DataTable();
            for (int n = 0; n < t1.Rows.Count; n++)
                temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(n).Take(1).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 0):

use the filter in the datatable :

```
dt.Select("ID = 1");
```

Comment: The select statement returns an array of rows you can bind to.  In this case the array will hopefully contain just one record.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this..

```
    dt = new DataTable();          
    dt_Property.Columns.Add("Field1");
    int i = 0;
    DataRow row = null;
    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {               
            row = dt.NewRow();                    
            row["Field1"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1];
            dt_Property.Rows.Add(row);   
            i = i + 1;
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: dt and dt_Property is same or not?